# Excel reference issue -formula does not copy properly

Tags: excel-formula, reference

Hello dear Excel users,

I have a column range with a formula that is copied. When I insert a new row the references in the formula do not change in the cell above which I have inserted the new blank row. The funny thing is that the references change in the other cells below the row above which I inserted the row.

Here is an example:
I have this formula in row 53 (cell L53)

```
=IF($O53="Subtotal",SUMIF($AK$40:$AK52,"Subtotal"&(COUNTIF($O$40:$O52,"Subtotal")+1),$L$40:$L52),0)
```

When I insert a new row above row 53 the formula in row 54 (the old row 53) remains the same while it should change the references from row 52 to 53 respectively. So here is the formula after I insert the new row:

```
=IF($O54="Subtotal",SUMIF($AK$40:$AK52,"Subtotal"&(COUNTIF($O$40:$O52,"Subtotal")+1),$L$40:$L52),0)
```

So some of the references have changes while others remain the same.

The formulas on the rows below are corrects:

```
=IF($O55="Subtotal",SUMIF($AK$40:$AK54,"Subtotal"&(COUNTIF($O$40:$O54,"Subtotal")+1),$L$40:$L54),0)
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: notice you are working on rows `40:52`. Common behaviour of Excel is exactly what you are getting. Because the range `40:52` have not changed (like inserting a new row **between** rows 40 and 52), relative references won't update if you insert a new row **after** row 52.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am still trying to get my head around this issue. One way is to use the offset function with row().